# iso file not recognized by Win7 or pendrive installer

Tags: iso

When I follow the CD instructions from ubuntu win7 gives "selected disk image isn't valid" and pendrive installer doesn't see the .iso file. I can see it with windows explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add some more details about the situation. What you are trying to do and what happened?. What do you mean by "Pendrive installer"?

Comment: I'm downloading Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS 64 bit. Pendrive is the recommended usb installer on the main ubuntu download page. Checksums don't match. I''m going try retry my downloads.

Comment: @aking1012 You might want to make an answer from your comment, since Alex has indicated that the MD5SUM indicated a corrupted `.iso` image (so he'd probably accept your answer, assuming that's the only problem, which is most likely).

Comment: I did get a good download and tried making a bootable usb drive per the instructions. The process ran without any error messages but it hangs in syslinux, I'll dig into that next.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you got a bad/corrupted download.

[Download the gnu md5sum utility for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and check the disk's sum against the sum it should be...

We need to find out if it's actually a bad image before we can fix the problem